# How to select a subsequence of a list based on unique value in a property

Tags: c#, linq, sequence, projection, subset

I have a class and a list of it like this:

```
public class Person {
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public DateTime Birthday { get; set; }
}

// and my list is:
var persons = new List<Person>();
persons.add(/* add for example 20 person here */);
```

These persons may have duplicate `FirstName` and `LastName`. I want to select a subsequence of persons that all `FirstName` vs `LastName` are diferent. I mean my primary-key (in a relational db vision) is `FirstName + LastName`.

I know I can do this by iterating the list. But I'm asking a `LINQ` solution. Is there any one? May I select the specified subsequence by `LINQ`? Any idea please?

Comment: You can implement `IEqualityComparer<Person>` in a `PersonComparer` class and pass an object of `PersonComparer` to LINQ `Distinct` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a [`Lookup<TKey, TElement> Class`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb460184.aspx) based on `FirstName+LastName` key and take only the first from each subcollection (as soon as you never said anything about it's rder or something) through [Enumerable.ToLookup Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549073.aspx) and [Enumerable.Select Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548891.aspx):

```
var result = persons.ToLookup(p => string.Concat(p.FirstName, p.LastName))
                    .Select(l => l.First());
```

Comment: That is exactly wath I want. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You want only unique Persons? You can use `Enumerable.GroupBy`, then count each group:

```
var uniquePersons = persons 
                   .GroupBy(p => new { p.FirstName, p.LastName })
                   .Where(g => g.Count() == 1)
                   .Select(g => g.First());
```

Here's a demo: http://ideone.com/nsbyyI

Comment: Thanks to help, but not only unique persons. Actually I want to select from persons that have a same firstname and lastname just one of them. I mean delete persons that occurs more that one, and just keep one of each. (My English is too bad :( sorry)